# What is the difference between class and styleClass attributes in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-7

I see, that in JSF most of the standard components that mapped to HTML tags, e.g. `<h:commandButton/>`, have attributes `class` and `styleClass`. But no matter, which one I use, both is rendered as `class` attributes in markup.

So why there are two attributes with the same purpose?

Comment: commandbutton does not have a class attribute.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is simply no `class` attribute in JSF components.

From the doc, attribute `styleClass` :

> Space-separated list of CSS style class(es) to be applied when this element is rendered. This value must be passed through as the "class" attribute on generated markup.

The `styleClass` is simply converted as `class` in the rendered HTML.

**More info :**

- [h:commandButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html)

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad. I was experimenting with [HTML5 Friendly Markup](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets009.htm) in JSF and for some reason start thinking that plain JSF components has `class` attribute as well. Thanks for the link to documentation.

Answer (score 3):

See this references:

http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/commandButton.shtml

http://www.developersbook.com/jsf/jsf-tags-reference/html/commandButton.php

**style**: If you want ot add any CSS with the component then you can put the style as the value of the attribute. Added CSS will be applied on for the component.

**styleClass**: This attribute holds the CSS class name which is defined in the external style sheet.

The attribute **style** in JSF is equivalent to attribute **style** in HTML.

The attribute **styleClass** in JSF is equivalent to attribute **class** in HTML.

Regards