# What is the difference between class and styleClass attributes?

Tags: css, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces component but I don't understand difference between styleClass and class. I can use both of them and I don't see any difference. What is the difference between class and styleClass attributes in PrimeFaces?

Comment: so you are saying that `<p:inputText ... class="red" .../>` and `<p:inputText ... styleClass="red" .../>` both with the same css class definition result in te same look and feel in the browser?

Comment: Does this only happen with PrimeFaces components or also plain jsf? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884950/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-styleclass-attributes-in-jsf. And please state version info of both PF and jsf (including implementation) and post an [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact in **JSF** and **Primefaces**:

- `styleClass` is used to specify classes to JSF components, it will be then
  converted to a `class` attribute in the rendered HTML code.
- And `class` attribute is used with HTML elements, and can't be used directly with JSF components.

And when you open any JSF tag documentation, you will see that:

> **styleClass**
>
> The styleClass attribute sets the CSS class to apply to this component
>   when it is rendered.

You can see **[JSF h:outputText tag](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html)** for example.

Comment: your answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884950/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-styleclass-attributes-in-jsf. But It **seems** (not sure, therefor I requested confirmation) the OP says that a class attribute **is** usable on PF components

Comment: @Kukeltje No in fact the other answer only define the `styleClass`property, and here I am explaining the use of each property and the tags that accepts it, It's similar yes but it's more detailed here.

Comment: If you say so... To me this answer and the other one are identical.

Comment: That's you point of vue ;). It only includes **JSF** here beacuse **Primefaces** is built on JSF.